# For each function in class within python

Tags: python, reflection, oop

In python is it possible to run each function inside a class?

**EDIT:**
What i am trying to do is call of the functions inside a class, collect their return variables and work with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "function".  Something like this could work, though:

```
import inspect

def methods(c):
    return (m for m in (getattr(c, d) for d in dir(c))
            if inspect.ismethoddescriptor(m) or inspect.ismethod(m))
```

Then:

```
class C:
    def f(self): pass

>>> list(methods(C))
[<unbound method C.f>]
```

Comment: -1 For sticking the entire expression in the return statement making in entirely unreadable.

Answer (score 4):

yes, you can.
Quick and dirty:

```
class foo:
    def one(self):
        print "here is one"
    def two(self):
        print "here is two"
    def three(self):
        print "here is three"


obj = foo()
for entry in dir(obj):
    print entry, callable(getattr(obj,entry))
    if callable(getattr(obj,entry)):
        getattr(obj,entry)()
```

If you want a more refined concept, check the unittest.py module. There should be code that executes all methods starting with the string "test"

Answer (score 3):

The [`dir` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) will list all attributes of an object, for example:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def one(self):
...         print "one"
...     def two(self):
...         print "two"
...     def three(self):
...         print "three"
... 
>>> dir(MyClass)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'one', 'three', 'two']
```

It also works on an initialised class..

```
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> dir(c)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'one', 'three', 'two']
```

Methods are just attributes which happen to be callable (via `c.attribute()` ) - we can use the `getattr` function to reference that method via a variable..

```
>>> myfunc = getattr(c, 'one')
>>> myfunc
<bound method MyClass.one of <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x7b0d0>>
```

Then we can simply call that variable..

```
>>> myfunc()
one # the output from the c.one() method
```

Since some attributes are not functions (in the above example, `__doc__` and `__module__`). We can us the [callable builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable) to check if it's a callable method (a function):

```
>>> callable(c.three)
True
>>> callable(c.__doc__)
False
```

So to combine all that into a loop:

```
>>> for cur_method_name in dir(c):
...     the_attr = getattr(c, cur_method_name)
...     if callable(the_attr):
...             the_attr()
... 
one
three
two
```

Remember this will call methods like `__init__` again, which probably isn't desired. You might want to skip any `cur_method_name` which start with an underscore

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that uses yield to loop through the functions in the class.

```
def get_functions(mod):
    for entry in dir(mod):
        obj=getattr(mod,entry);
        if hasattr(obj, '__call__') and hasattr(obj,'__func__') :
            yield obj

class foo:
    def one(self):
        print ("here is two")
        return 1
    def two(self):
        print ("here is two")
        return 2
    def three(self):
        print ("here is three")
        return 3


print(sum([fun() for fun in get_functions(foo())]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote the class, you already *know* all the functions.

```
class ThisIsPeculiar( object ):
    def aFunction( self, arg1 ):
        pass
    def anotherFunction( self, thisArg, thatArg ):
        pass
    functionsToCall = [ aFunction, anotherFunction ]

>>> p= ThisIsPeculiar()
>>> p.functionsToCall
[<function aFunction at 0x6b830>, <function anotherFunction at 0x6b870>]
```

Comment: Yeah, but that violates the Don't Repeat Yourself principle. Besides, he may not own the code that he wants to exercise, or not want to add unnecessary turds.

Comment: Doesn't seem to violate DRY to me.  You can easily have methods you don't want called automagically.  This positively identifies the list of methods which are called.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html):

```
import inspect

class Spam:
    def eggs(self):
        print "eggs"
    def ducks(self):
        print "ducks"
    value = "value"

spam = Spam()
for name, method in inspect.getmembers(spam, callable):
    method()
```

Output:

```
ducks
eggs
```